# Cannot read property '@' of null when using $state in onEnter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am get the following error from the angular-ui-router:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '@' of null
...
TypeError: Cannot read property '@main' of null
...
```

I have done some research on what could be the cause of this error and have come to the conclusion that the problem lies with the the fact that I do a redirect when a condition is false through a $state.go(state) during an onEnter of another state.

Here are some discussions concerning the same issue on github:

- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1234
- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1434

I tried some of the suggestions, but they are not working. They don't seem to provide a solution, but just point out the problem, and according to [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/516) github discussion it should be resolved, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I am using AngularJS v1.2.24 and ui-router v0.2.11.

Using the following code (simplified):

```
.state('main', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: '/main/_layout.html'
})
.state('main.home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '/main/home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    onEnter: function ($state)
    {
        if (condition === true){
            $state.go('main.catch')
        }
    }
})
.state('main.catch', {
    url: '/catch',
    templateUrl: '/main/catch/catch.html',
    controller: 'CatchCtrl'
})
```

Is there a way to get this to work? Or should I consider a completely different approach to achieve the same result?

P.S.: A possible fix is to do the following in the controller,

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(){
    // conditional redirect here
}
```

But I don't want to do it in the HomeCtrl.

Comment: are you redirecting from `main.catch` to `main.catch`?

Comment: oeps, this is a typo. It redirects to main.catch from main.home => corrected

Comment: Wouldn't it help if you put the condition into resolve instead of onEnter?

Comment: have a look at this you can define a function in the state and should be able to redirect there https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: @ stackg91 lol, yes I did. PS in the mean time I am able to solve this and will be answering to this issue shortly myself. A little low on time atm ;)

Comment: @tomastrajan that is a part of the solution idd

Comment: @bohem.be, have you find solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered a similar situation, and solved it this way:

```
.state('main.home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '/main/home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    onEnter: function ($state)
    {
        if (condition === true){
            $timeout(function() {
                $state.go('main.catch')
            )};
        }
    }
})
```

The trick is that you want to let the original state change finish rather than trying to redirect in the middle of the state change.  The $timeout allows the original state change to finish, and then immediately fire off the change to the desired state.

Comment: Rather than using $timeout, I'd recommend using the `$state.transition` property, if it's there (otherwise, no `$timeout` is needed, and it'll fire without relying on the clock being correct.) For example, try this: `function afterTransition($state, action) {
        if ($state.transition) {
            $state.transition.finally(action);
        }
        else {
            action();
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

well, I know it's a little bit late but I've been having this problem for a long time and I finally solved it by listening to the `$viewContentLoading` event:

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoading', function(){
    if(!$state.$current.locals)
      $state.$current.locals = {};
});
```